# Broken network after KVM installation

Tags: networking

I have started to traverse through instructions on KVM installation without realising that I was not SSHing to my server and performing everything on my local machine. I have got as fas as installing the following

```
sudo apt install qemu qemu-kvm libvirt-bin  bridge-utils  virt-manager
```

and

```
sudo apt install netplan
```

After purging and auto removing I have ended up with a non functional network.

```
lshw -C network
```

shows my adapter as disabled. After `ifconfig up enp3s0` it appears in if config but still not functional. I have tried various configurations. The outcome is that /`etc/network/interfaces` is completely ignored by the system because of parameter in `NetworkManager.conf`. When I set `managed= false`, the interface obtains some strange ipv6 address, but not ipv4 in both static and DHCP configurations. Configuring via GUI did not lead to any significant result.

I would really appreciate any advice on this, because the only solution for me now is the full system re-installation, which is not really optimal by any means